# Calculate Air Conditioning Duct Pressure from Sources and Users

Tags: pressure, airflow, hvac, aircraft-design

I am currently modeling a high fidelity simulation of Boeing 747-200 for a flight simulator, and I am now at the stage of programming what is essentially the HVAC system for the aircraft.

I will try to keep aviation jargon out of this unless it is necessary, for simplicity sake

Here is what I know about the system:

The aircraft has four engines, each of which can supply compressed air to the main air conditioning supply duct. The pressure (in PSI) of the air in the duct is directly output to a gauge on the flight engineer panel, and it is this gauge output that I am ultimately wanting to arrive at.

The compressed air from each engine is controlled via a regulator valve to a maximum of 47 psi with no flow, and 40 psi with 150 lbs/min flow (which seems to be the design maximum for each engine). With all four engines running, the theoretical supply is thus ~600 lbs/min, assuming standard conditions. I assume that 'flow' in these cases refers to how much air is flowing out of the supply duct into the AC units (i.e. having to be replaced by the engines).

There are 3 air conditioning units (PACKS in aviation terms) that are connected to this air conditioning supply duct, each can be turned off or on individually.

These air conditioning units are controlled semi-automatically, and require a minimum of 8 PSI in the duct to run (the valve will close automatically if the duct pressure is less than 8 PSI). The valve also controls the mass flow rate into the air conditioning unit: according to my manuals, the valve is fully open until duct pressure exceeds ~30 PSI, no further details are given about this function or about exactly how much airflow the AC units require, however the airflow gauges on the flight engineer's panel for each AC unit have a green band (indicating correct operation) between 1500 and 3300 CFM.

The ducting between the engines and the point at which the pressure is measured as well as where the AC packs are supplied is 6 inches in diameter, I do not know what material it is made of but the temperature of the air supplied by engines before going into the AC units is ~175C if that makes a difference. The duct has a design leakage rate of about 300 SCFM at 45 PSI.

What I would like to calculate is the duct pressure, as it would be indicated on the flight engineer's gauge, based upon the inputs and outputs of the system. What formula or set of formulas can I use to determine what the pressure in the duct is at any given moment based upon the input and the output of the system?

Thanks!
Chris

Comment: As an update, some more information about the system: each AC unit/PACK attempts to regulate the mass flow rate to 200 ppm (2500 CFM), and the ducts are made of fiberglass.